# How to display a symbol or short expression inside a circle?

Tags: plotting, labeling, frame

I need some fast way of putting insets on the graph, where some numbers or symbols are enclosed in a circle (to label curves on a plot). Is there some command to produce such pictures, equivalent to `Frame["a"]`, only with a circular frame?

Comment: `Framed[1/x + y, ImageMargins -> 20, RoundingRadius -> 30]`

Comment: This is an interesting question, but in trying to come up a solution I find it under-specified. How do you want the your circular labels placed? Do you want explicit control over the position or do you want Mathematica to do the placement with some guidance such as `Automatic`, `Left`, `Right`, `Botom`, `Top`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
Plot[Sin@t, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Epilog ->
  {
   Inset[Graphics[{Text["A"], Circle[]}, ImageSize -> 30], {1.5, +0.5}],
   Inset[Graphics[{Text["B"], Circle[]}, ImageSize -> 30], {4.5, -0.5}]
   }]
```

[image]

This can be turned into a function:

```
circle[text_, pos_] :=
 Inset[Graphics[{Text[text], Circle[]}, ImageSize -> 30], pos]

Plot[Sin@t, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Epilog ->
  {
   circle["A", {1.5, +0.5}],
   circle["B", {4.5, -0.5}]
   }]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, 
 {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotLabels -> {Text[Style["1",18]],
                Text[Style["2",18]]}]
```

or

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, 
 {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> {Text[Style["1", 18]], 
                 Text[Style["2", 18]]}]
```

or

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, 
     {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> {Framed[Text[Style["1", 14]], RoundingRadius -> 50], 
   Framed[Text[Style["2", 14]], RoundingRadius -> 50]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
symbol = {Text[Style["Sin[x]", Blue, Italic, 12], loc],
    Thick, Red, Circle[loc, 1/4 {1, 1/2}]} /. loc -> {1, 1/2};

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, \[Pi]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, \[Pi]}, {0, 1}}, Epilog -> symbol]
```

Getting the circle to look like a circle instead of an ellipse is the real trick.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

```
ellipseframe[text_, pos_] := 
 Inset[Framed[text, RoundingRadius -> 50], pos]
circleframe[text_, pos_] := 
 Inset[Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, Scaled[0.1]], Inset[text]}], pos]
```

Which give

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, Epilog -> ellipseframe["Text", {3 π/2, 0.5}]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, Epilog -> circleframe["Text", {3 π/2, 0.5}]]
```

[image]

`circleframe` is pretty kludgy -- I haven't built in anything to determine how big the circle should be. But if you really want your frame to be a circle, that might be a way to go. `ellipseframe` is much nicer, and scales automatically:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, 
  Epilog -> ellipseframe["Lots and\nlots and lots\nof text", {3 π/2, 0.5}]
]
```

[image]